# Nvidia driver for kernel with acs patch

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 18.10

I am using 18.10 with the latest mainline kernel 5.x with the acs patch so I can use gpu pass through.

But as soon as I use a kernel with the acs patch (I also tried 4.18) the nvidia driver refuses to load as the kernel-driver for the card I don't want to pass through.

The result is I am stuck at a low resolution (I was impressed that I got graphics at all with neither nouveau nor nvidia drivers)

The pass through is working and vfio is grabbing the other card fine.

For now I am using nouveau, but since it lacks vulkan support I'd like to have the nividia driver working.

What I tried:

from the ppa graphics driver:

```
nvidia-driver-410
nvidia-driver-415
nvidia-driver-418

nvidia-dkms-415
nvidia-dkms-418
```

I am somewhat hesitant to use the nvidia installer since I had bad experience with it.

Comment: the one who downvoted this question, would you care to explain why? so i can improve my question.

Comment: yes it is, i am using version ubuntu 18.10 with a version 5 kernes with the acs patch

Comment: Oh... mainline kernel 5.0.x that was JUST released? If you boot to the standard kernel, without any patches, does it work that way? The Nvidia driver is probably not compatible with kernel 5.0.x. Exactly what is this patch?

Comment: Yes, i also tried older Kernels (eg 4.18.x) without luck. The acs patch enables the Kernel to move every PCI device into its own IOMMU group so they can be isolated and passed through to a kvm guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia released a beta driver recently to support the version 5.x Kernels.

you have to use their runfile installer from https://www.nvidia.de/drivers/beta to make it work.

It requires several restarts and needs to be installed from a terminal when no gnome or x session (or any other graphical desktop environment) is running.

I run kvm with a dedicated gpu (1060) now on 5.x with 418.43 and a normal gpu for the system (1080)

i tried every other driver from every ppa i could find and i downgraded my kernel till 4.14.

But only the latets beta (418.43) directly from nvidia (with dkms) worked.

So the conclusion is:

When you want to have gpu pass through AND the latest updates you have to use nvidias clunky installer.